# Rotate arrow indicator in React-select v2

Tags: reactjs, react-select

I'm using React Select v2 in my project with Styled Components and I need to be able to turn the arrow indicator upside down when the menu is open, which was supported in v1.

I kinda managed to do it by doing this:

```
   css`
     &.react-select__control--is-focused {
       & .react-select__indicators {
         & .react-select__dropdown-indicator {
           transform: rotate(180deg);
         }
       }
     }
   `;
```

Problem is that, if I press the arrow to open the menu and click on it again to close it, the arrow stays upside down because the select is still focused, which feels a bit weird in terms of UIX.

Is there a proper way to rotate it based on the state of the menu? I looked for something in the documentation but I couldn't find it.

Maybe I missed it, if someone could point me in the right direction, that'd be awesome!

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, based on Laura's response, my solution was to use the `onMenuClose` and `onMenuOpen` to set the state of a property in my styled component.

```
const indicatorStyle = (props: StyledSelectProps & DropdownProps<{}>) => css`
  & .react-select__indicators {
      & .react-select__dropdown-indicator {
        transition: all .2s ease;
        transform: ${props.isOpen && "rotate(180deg)"};
      }
    }
`;
```

This function is called inside of my styled component's css.

And then in the component I call my styled component, I control the state:

```
export class Dropdown<TValue> extends React.Component<DropdownProps<TValue>> {
  public state = { isOpen: false };

  private onMenuOpen = () => this.setState({ isOpen: true });
  private onMenuClose = () => this.setState({ isOpen: false });

  public render() {
    const { ...props } = this.props;
    const { isOpen } = this.state;
    return (
      <StyledSelect {...props} isOpen={isOpen} onMenuOpen={this.onMenuOpen} onMenuClose={this.onMenuClose} />
    );
  }
}
```

A bit convoluted but it works for now.

Comment: You should only animate `transform` (`transition: transform .2s ease;`)

Answer (score 12):

Technically you can use the style-in-JS props of the v2. Like the following example:

```
dropdownIndicator: (base, state) => ({
    ...base,
    transition: 'all .2s ease',
    transform: state.isFocused ? 'rotate(180deg)' : null
  })
```

It seems that the `isFocused` state isn't bind with the `isMenuOpen` state but with the real `focus` state of the container.

A solution is to set `closeMenuOnSelect={false}` so the user would have to click outside the select and your arrow will flip back.

Or you could change the `className` props using `onMenuOpen` and `onMenuClose` by adding a specific suffix to target your animation.

**UPDATE**

You can directly access the `menuOpen` props via the `state` so no need to manually add class like the following:

```
dropdownIndicator: (base, state) => ({
  ...base,
  transition: 'all .2s ease',
  transform: state.selectProps.menuIsOpen ? 'rotate(180deg)' : null
})
```

**PLEASE NOTE THAT**

In `react-select` v2.3 a `control--menu-is-open` has been added directly  in the code.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that and let you know!

Comment: So, the solution with the style-in-js and `closeMenuOnSelect` doesn't work because the arrow doesn't rotate back when the user clicks on the dropdown itself again as it stays on focus.
The solution with `onMenuOpen` and `onMenuClose` does work but it's a bit convoluted IMO. I'm going with that one for now.
Thanks!

Comment: You should open an issue in GitHub for that, I agree that it feels a little bit hacky and needs to be fixed.

Comment: Good idea, I opened this issue: https://github.com/JedWatson/react-select/issues/2926

Comment: thanks! btw `state.selectProps.menuIsOpen` also works for react-select v5

Answer (score 6):

This worked for me

```
<select styles={{
            dropdownIndicator: (provided, state) => ({
              ...provided,
              transform: state.selectProps.menuIsOpen && "rotate(180deg)"
            })
          }}
/>
```

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me.

```
  dropdownIndicator: (base, state) => ({
    ...base,
    transform: state.selectProps.menuIsOpen ? 'rotate(-90deg)' : 'rotate(0)',
    transition: '250ms',
  }),
```

Answer (score 0):

i solved this issue like this.

mostly you have to play arround with these in your css to do stuff on certain conditions

--is-focused

--menu-is-open

--is-disabled

--is-selected

styled component css

```
    .paginatorPageSizeCustomSelectPreffix__indicator {
      svg {
        color: var(--black);
        height: 18px;
        width: 18px;
        transform: rotate(180deg);
        transition: 0.2s;
      }
    }

    .paginatorPageSizeCustomSelectPreffix__control--menu-is-open {
      .paginatorPageSizeCustomSelectPreffix__indicator {
        svg {
          color: var(--black);
          height: 18px;
          width: 18px;
          transform: rotate(360deg);
          transition: 0.2s;
        }
      }
    }
  }
```