# React-Select : How to rotate dropdown indicator when menu open

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-select

in example : https://codesandbox.io/s/jz33xx66q9?module=/example.js

i want to rotate emoji to up size down when menu open

how to do that

Comment: do you mean up side down?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Rotate arrow indicator in React-select v2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51761008/rotate-arrow-indicator-in-react-select-v2)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`react-select` provides a [styling api](https://react-select.com/styles) which offers such customization. Each attribute in the object given to the `styles` prop is a function which is getting the current component state as a prop. The state also has props from the base component (`Select`).

```
<Select
    { ... }
    styles={{
        dropdownIndicator: (provided, state) => ({
            ...provided,
            transform: state.selectProps.menuIsOpen && 'rotate(180deg)'
        })
    }}
/>
```

[CodeSandbox example](https://codesandbox.io/embed/yompxp201?fontsize=14)